# retrieving data and putting it in an excel sheet using Selenium C#

Tags: excel, selenium, xpath

Im navigating to https://www.nba.com/standings. (Its too much to copy and paste so I copied the web address). What I want to do is retrieve data from any 2 teams (random or specific), one from the Eastern conference and one from the Western conference... I want the team name, data in the Win column, loss column and win percentage. I want my Selenium test(C#) to fetch the data and save to an excel file.
Im having issues with writing an XPath because at the top level, the class name is the same for Eastern and Western conference Eastern Conference and Western Conference. The class name for each team is . Im not sure how to access a fetch specific column data and for the given team.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have tried to retrieve specific teams by the link text ---> IWebElement teamdata = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[@linktext='Indiana Pacers'")); but was unsuccessful. I even tried to fetch a specific row, by its class name but nothing is working.

Comment: I think you just want "//a[@text()='Indiana Pacers']"   and fix balanced quotes etc...  You'll want to use something more unique than class names.  IDs are designed to be unique, while style names are not.

Comment: btw, there does seem to be some free API's out there for NBA.  Not a clue as to how reliable or accurate they are.  I think the NBA also has their own with some free features.

Comment: Which data are you looking at?